# Elixir fsm and Exactor takes ages to respond

Tags: elixir, erlang-otp, fsm

I'm currently building a chatbot using Nadia, fsm and Exactor. I'm trying to model every  user conversation as a finite state machine to have reference of each state every user is currently in and use a cache to have a reference between the users chat id and its corresponding pid of the fsm they're using.

I based my design on [this tutorial](https://isotope11.com/blog/a-tour-of-finite-state-machines-in-elixir-part-2)

The following snippet creates the pid but it gets stuck whenever I try to transition to the next state (polling)

```
  defp create(id) do
    {:ok, pid} = start_link()
    Cache.get_or_create(:teleid2pid, id, pid)
    IO.inspect "Changing to polling"
    start_polling(pid, id)
    pid
 end

def pid_or_create(id) do
  pid = Cache.get_value(:teleid2pid, id)
  case  pid do
    nil -> create(id)
     _ -> pid
    end
 end
```

I create the possible events using the following code based on the example found on the [fsm library's github page](https://github.com/sasa1977/fsm)

```
  @one_arity_events [:start_polling, :edit_info, :update_db]
  for event <- @one_arity_events do
    defcall unquote(event)(data), state: fsm do
      FlowFsm.unquote(event)(fsm, data)
      |> new_state
    end
  end
```

And for this particular example this is the event that I'm calling

```
  defstate start do
     defevent start_polling(id) do
     next_state(:polling, get_user_info(id))
   end
 end
```

But the get_user_info function isn't causing the slowdown 
This is an example using iEx

```
  iex(1)> alias TelegramBot.FsmServer
  TelegramBot.FsmServer
  iex(2)> alias TelegramBot.FlowFsm
  TelegramBot.FlowFsm
  iex(3)> pid = FsmServer.pid_or_create("1")
  [debug] QUERY OK source="users" db=2.7ms decode=2.6ms
  "Changing to polling"
   ** (exit) exited in: GenServer.call(#PID<0.334.0>, {:start_polling,"1"}, 5000)
  ** (EXIT) time out
 (elixir) lib/gen_server.ex:774: GenServer.call/3
 (backend) 
 lib/backend/telegram_chatbot/fsm/fsm_server.ex:19: 
 TelegramBot.FsmServer.create/1
 iex(3)> pid = FsmServer.pid_or_create("1")
 #PID<0.334.0>
 iex(4)> FsmServer.state(pid)
:polling
iex(5)> FlowFsm.get_user_info("1")        
%{db_id: 1, telegram_id: "1"}
```

The FSM data structure works by itself if I call it without making use of the FsmServer.

What could be causing this massive lag ? 
Or better yet, how could I manage multiple instances of FSM's  concurrently?

Comment: Looks like a [deadlock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock). What does `start_polling` do? Can you post the complete code of this module?

Comment: I just updated it with some more info and added this hastebin of the FsmServer module and the Fsm data structure.

https://hastebin.com/simetibave.sql

Comment: I've never used ExActor so the syntax is foreign to me, but this problem usually happens if you make a GenServer `call` from within another `call` or `cast`. Since only one message is processed at a time, the second call will not execute before the current one exits and that results in a timeout.

Comment: Oh, that actually helped me a lot, I'll update the question with the change that fixed the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I was calling the genserver inside of the genserver so it ended up in a Deadlock as Dogbert suggested, to fix this I modified the start_link and create function like this

```
defstart start_link(id), do: initial_state(create_fsm(id))

defp create(id) do
  {:ok, pid} = start_link(id)
  Cache.get_or_create(:teleid2pid, id, pid)
  pid
end

defp create_fsm(id) do
  FlowFsm.new
  |> FlowFsm.start_polling(id)
end
```